# Jquery click link send information to php

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, hyperlink

I'm creating a system using jquery and php that pops up a small div when they get a private message on my website. The alert itself I have figured out, but I'm not sure how to gracefully cancel it.

I've made it so that clicking a link "[x]" hides the div, but how can I make the link send enough information to a php script to mark this alert as "read" in the database?

All the php script would need is the id of the alert in the database, but I've got no idea how to make it do that. There is also more than one notice displayed at a time, so I would need a way to have each link send the information necessary to the php script.

Here's the jquery that loads the div and the php that powers it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#mc').load('/lib/message_center.php').show("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.delete').live('click', function(){
          $('#mc').hide('slow');

    });
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `href` attribute for your X produced by php like `href="javascript:killbox(5);"` and give your div a unique id (i.e.`id="boxtokill5"`). Then you could use something like this:

```
function killbox(id){
    $("#boxtokill"+id).hide();
    var packet = {};
    packet.clickedlinkid = id;
    $.get("destination.php",packet,function(data){
      // data = Response (output) from script
    });
}
```

The `destination.php` receives the ID by `$_GET['clickedlink']`.

Comment: If it is enough for you that that the message is displayed to the user then you should use jeroen's solution to prevent unecessary communication...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to set the message you are displaying to read at the moment you display it. That would not require any additional communication between the browser and the server, just do it at the end of your `/lib/message_center.php` script for the messages you are displaying at that moment.